# Best Practice to find nearby based on lat/lon android?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have 16000 Locations in my Sql Lite DB.

And I am fetching all into cursor and setting each into LOCATION object and I am using distaneTo() method of LOCATION class.

Is there any best way to do it to find nearest Location based on user's location.

My Code::::

```
Location userLocation = new Location("Point A");
        userLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        userLocation.setLongitude(longitude);

        Location stopLocation = new Location("Point B");

        List<FavouriteStop> allFavourites = new ArrayList<FavouriteStop>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
                "Select * from tbl_stop order by routeName desc", null);

        FavouriteStop stop = new FavouriteStop();
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stopId")) != null) {

                    // Setting Stop Location for Distance
                    stopLocation.setLatitude(c.getDouble(c
                            .getColumnIndex("lat")));
                    stopLocation.setLongitude(c.getDouble(c
                            .getColumnIndex("lon")));

                    float distance = userLocation.distanceTo(stopLocation);
                    if (distance < radius) {

                        if (allStopsHash.containsKey(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("routeName")))) {
                            // Contains
                        } else {
                            // Not Contain
                            stop.setFirstElement(true);
                            allStopsHash.put(
                                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("routeName")),
                                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("routeName")));
                        }

                        stop.settag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("tag")));
                        stop.settitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));
                        stop.setlat(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("lat")));
                        stop.setlon(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("lon")));
                        stop.setstopId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stopId")));
                        stop.setDirection(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("towards")));
                        stop.setRouteName(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("routeName")));
                        stop.setDistance((distance / 1000));

                        allFavourites.add(stop);
                        // }
                    }// Distance Radius Over
                }// If StopId != Null Over
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
```

Comment: Window is full: requested allocation 36 bytes, free space 4 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes

Comment: I am having this warning to...Any solution

Answer (score 0):

SQLite can't do queries sorted by distance based on coordinates. Iterating through the points is the right solution in this case. However, you can improve your implementation by caching the column indexes. Instead of calling multiple times getColumnIndex("lat") for example you can have something like

```
int latIndex = getColumnIndex("lat");
```

and than always use latIndex. I've never done tests to check the performance improvement but it's certainly the better way of doing it.